# Stylus starts to write "too early"

Tags: 18.04, stylus

I installed Ubuntu recently on my Dell Inspiron 7386 2-in-1 and noticed, that my pen is not writing properly. 
I use Xournal and the problem is, that when I put down my pen, Ubuntu starts to write where my cursor was at that moment. And since the cursor is always dragging behind, the line always starts "behind" my pen, jumps to the plays where I actually touched the Screen and then starts to write normal. [image: Screenshot in Xournal]

Thanks in advance for helping!

Comment: I have a similar problem. Can you post the output of "xinput list" ?

Comment: Can you also check the behavior in Xournal while you're pressing the buttons?